# Javascript Firebase RealTime Database Completion Block

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to understand firebase-realtime-database. I am able to fetch the data, but I do not know how to add a completion block. I mean, is there a function to check when my data fetch query is completed?

```
function getData() { 
  firebase.database().ref('SectionNames').once('value', function(names) {    
    names.val().forEach(function(sectionname) { 
      firebase.database().ref('Sections').child(sectionname).once('value').then( function(child)  

      //code

    });   
   });
  });
 //Completion block or a method to call processData() after I get all the sections
}

function processData() {
 //call this function after you get all the sections
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `once()` method also returns a promise, so you can use the usual promise handling logic (`then()`/`catch()` or `try`/`catch`).

For example:

```
function getData() async { 
  let names = await firebase.database().ref('sections').once('value');
  processData(names);
}
```

---

**Update**: since you now updated your code to show there are multiple `once` calls in a loop, you can use a `Promise.all` for that:

```
function getData() { 
  firebase.database().ref('SectionNames').once('value', function(names) {    
    let promises = [];
    names.val().forEach(function(sectionname) { 
      promises.push( 
        firebase.database().ref('Sections').child(sectionname).once('value')
      );
    });   
    Promise.all(promises).then((snapshots) => {
      processData(snapshots);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I have to edit my question. There is a nested query.

Comment: You can either count whether you've loaded all data, or you can use `Promise.all` to wait until all `once()` calls are compelte.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I have understood.

Comment: Good to hear. Going forward please don't change the original code in your question substantially, as the first part of my answer now makes no sense to developers who come here in the future. Instead, add the clarifying code in an update at the bottom of your question.

Comment: Oh yes. I will make changes to my post. Thank you once again.